# Sampling with a key in different data table using data.table in 'R'

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following code.

```
DT <- data.table(s3ITR)
DTKey <- data.table(s3Key, key = "Age")
> DT
    Index Country Age Time Charity
 1:     1  France  30   40       1
 2:     2  France  40   40       0
 3:     3  France  40   50       0
 4:     4 Germany  40   40       1
 5:     5  France  60   40       1
 6:     6  France  40   40       1
 7:     7 Germany  30   40       0
 8:     8 Germany  30   40       1
 9:     9 Germany  30   40      NA
10:    10 Germany  30   40       1
> DTKey
   Index Country Age Time Charity
1:     1  France  30   40       0
2:     2 Germany  30   40       0
3:     3 Germany  30   40       1
4:     4 Germany  30   40       0
5:     5 Germany  30   40       1
6:     6 Germany  30   40       1
```

I would like to impute the NA in DT by random sample from DTKey, this may be stored in a new column called impute.

I can easily set a key within DT and sample from DT itself with the code below

```
DT <- data.table(s3ITR, key = "Age")
DT[, Impute := sample(na.omit(Charity), length(Charity), replace = T), by = key(DT)] 
DT[!is.na(Charity), Impute := Charity]
```

It is a bit convoluted, but it works and I get the result below

```
    Index Country Age Time Charity Impute
 1:     1  France  30   40       1      1
 2:     2  France  40   40       0      0
 3:     3  France  40   50       0      0
 4:     4 Germany  40   40       1      1
 5:     5  France  60   40       1      1
 6:     6  France  40   40       1      1
 7:     7 Germany  30   40       0      0
 8:     8 Germany  30   40       1      1
 9:     9 Germany  30   40      NA      1
10:    10 Germany  30   40       1      1
```

Where the probability of NA being imputed as 1 is 3/4. I would like to this exact same thing but sample from DTkey instead, where the probability would be 3/6.

Is there a easy way to do this without merging the tables ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a special reason why you want to sample from DTKey? To achieve a "fair" probability you could simply use:

`sample(0:1,1,replace=T)`

Assuming that Charity is either 0 or 1 respectively.

UPDATE:

Okay in that case you could try the following:

```
DT[, Impute:= sample(DTKey[,Charity], length(DT[,Charity]), replace=T)]
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a fair probability. What I'm trying to do is a simplified version of hot and cold deck imputation. 
Suppose people of age 30 have a probability of responding as 1 of 0.7 not 0.5 this model would account for that by sampling missing values of people of age 30 from a donor pool of people of the sample age, there by the probability of imputation as 1 will be 0.7.